# Is the term "sons of God" in John 1:12 the same categorization as "sons of God" in the OT (IE: Job 1:6)?

Tags: john, word-study, angels

The OT seems to have a consistent usage of the phrase "sons of God" as "angels" and the NT seems to ignore it completely. Or does it? Is there actually continuity?

> KJV John 1:12   But as many as received him, to them gave he power to
>   become **the sons of God**, even to them that believe on his name:

Is it possible that we've skewed the category and there is actually continuity? Might the category be broader, including both angels and adopted sons?

From the NT perspective, Adam also is a "son of God":

> KJV Luke_3:38  Which was the son of Enos, which was the son of Seth,
>   which was the son of **Adam, which was the son of God**

Also, does Jesus being a "son of God" suggest that he was an angel? I note that popular scholarship identifies Jesus as "the angel of the Lord" of the OT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of verse in John:

> ὅσοι δὲ ἔλαβον αὐτόν ἔδωκεν αὐτοῖς ἐξουσίαν **τέκνα θεοῦ** γενέσθαι τοῖς πιστεύουσιν εἰς τὸ ὄνομα αὐτοῦ (1:12)

The word [τέκνα](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5043&t=KJV) is most commonly translated as "children."

> But to all who did receive him, who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God (ESV)

The passage from Luke is not relevant to a word study:

> *the son* of Enosh, *the son* of Seth, *the son* of Adam, *the son* of God. (Luke 3:38 NKJV)
>
> τοῦ Ἐνὼς τοῦ Σὴθ τοῦ Ἀδὰμ τοῦ θεοῦ

The words "*the son*" are not in the Greek; they are added as an implied ellipsis. The actual text simply connects the names of the successive sons with the article [τοῦ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3588&t=KJV).

The passage in Job where the "sons" of God are going back and forth from the earth to the LORD, suggests these are angels which is how the LXX treats the passage:

> Job 1:6
> Now there was a day when the **sons of God** came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came among them. (ESV)
>
> και ως εγενετο η ημερα αυτη και ιδου ηλθον οι **αγγελοι του θεου** παραστηναι ενωπιον του κυριου και ο διαβολος ηλθεν μετ αυτων

The word [ἄγγελος](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G32&t=KJV) means angels. A word study of John should not connect the passage in Job.

"Sons of God" is also found in Genesis:

> Genesis 6:2
> the **sons of God** saw that the daughters of man were attractive. And they took as their wives any they chose. (ESV)
>
> ἰδόντες δὲ οἱ **υἱοὶ τοῦ θεοῦ** τὰς θυγατέρας τῶν ἀνθρώπων ὅτι καλαί εἰσιν, ἔλαβον ἑαυτοῖς γυναῖκας ἀπὸ πασῶν, ὧν ἐξελέξαντο. (LXX)

Here the Greek is  [υἱός](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5207&t=KJV) which means "son" which is how John writes the phrase "Son of God:"

> And I have seen and have borne witness that this is the Son of God.” (John 1:34 ESV)
>
> κἀγὼ ἑώρακα καὶ μεμαρτύρηκα ὅτι οὗτός ἐστιν ὁ **υἱὸς τοῦ θεοῦ**

It is unlikely John intends a reader to make a connection with Jesus and the Sons of God of Genesis 6. First he writes the Word was with God and the Word became flesh and was the [μονογενοῦς](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3439&t=KJV) which is the "only begotten." That is the Word is the **unique** Son of God. Additionally John states the Spirit was on Jesus before calling Him the "Son of God" (1:33) and immediately adds the description as "The Lamb of God." In others, it would be wrong to take "Son of God" in isolation. Jesus is the unique only begotten, Spirit filled, Son and Lamb of God.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even look at the Greek which as you point out is different in both cases. Excellent, thanks.

Comment: It's important to realize, however, that the translators of the LXX are giving a *dynamic* (but entirely justified) translation of the original Hebrew בני האלהים (the sons of God) in Job 1:6 and presumably elsewhere. Also Luke 3:23's υιος (son) *is implied* for all the following names in the genetive: I don't think they can stand alone! Great point about μονογενης as used of the only Son of God, I had forgotten about that.

Answer (score 0):

Not if Hebrews is in your Bible.

> **Hebrews 1 (DRB)** God, who, at sundry times and in divers manners, spoke in times past to the fathers by the prophets, last of all, 2 In these days hath spoken to us by **his Son,** whom he hath appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the world. 3 Who being the brightness of his glory, and the figure of his substance, and **upholding all things by the word of his power,** making purgation of sins, sitteth on the right hand of the majesty on high. 4 Being made so much better than the angels, as he hath inherited a more excellent name than they. 5 **For to which of the angels hath he said at any time, Thou art my Son,** to day have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him a Father, and he shall be to me **a Son?** 6 And again, when he bringeth in the first begotten into the world, he saith: **And let all the angels of God adore him.** 7 And **to the angels** indeed he saith: He that maketh his angels spirits, and his ministers a flame of fire. 8 **But to the Son:** Thy throne, O God, is for ever and ever: a sceptre of justice is the sceptre of thy kingdom. 9 Thou hast loved justice, and hated iniquity: therefore God, thy God, hath anointed thee with the oil of gladness above thy fellows. 10 And: Thou in the beginning, **O Lord,** didst found the earth: and the works of thy hands are the heavens. 11 They shall perish, but thou shalt continue: and they shall all grow old as a garment. 12 And as a vesture shalt thou change them, and they shall be changed: but thou art the selfsame, and thy years shall not fail. 13 **But to which of the angels** said he at any time: Sit on my right hand, until I make thy enemies thy footstool? 14 **Are they not all ministering spirits, sent to minister for them, who shall receive the inheritance of salvation?**

*The* Son of God could not be more clearly or emphatically distinguished from the angels who are endearingly considered 'sons' of God, as Adam was.

Comment: So was Jesus "the angel of YHVH"? And was his humanity not a later acquisition?

Comment: I used to be of that opinion, yet I am not entirely sure that the malak yhvh is not some angel of extremely high rank. I believe he is a *type* of Christ in many and various ways, without any doubt. But that is a question separate to this particular question.

Comment: I think the part we can agree on though is that his humanity (or reasonable facsimile thereof) was a later acquisition (Romans 1:4).

Comment: Well, yes, naturally the incarnation implies He wasn't flesh beforehand. I'm not sure Rom1:4 speaks of the incarnation, though. I'm not sure what is meant by a "facsimile" of Jesus' humanity.

Comment: The issue is whether Jesus was "fully human" or only "in the likeness of sinful flesh". Paul seems to suggest the latter.

Comment: Ah, Docetism. Not the place to debate that. But the first few verses of Romans ("of the seed of David according **to the flesh** ") precludes the 'likeness of sinful' flesh doesn't mean that it is *because He became flesh* whereas He wasn't. 1 John 4:2/2 John 1:7 is also pretty clear. Likeness always accompanies being the thing of which you are the likeness (*especially* when used of something that was purposefully changed into that thing so as to be part of it). The Word "became flesh."

Comment: The utterance becoming flesh is metaphor, not metaphysics. That is, the  message of God was communicated in a human life not that God's ability to speak became meat or physically human. We know this because later God speaks from the sky and says "This is my beloved son...".  YLT Heb 1:1In many parts, and many ways, God of old having spoken to the fathers in the prophets, 2in these last days **did speak to us in a Son**, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He did make the ages;

Comment: ("Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?") Would you like to take this to chat?

Comment: Not really, thanks. But we can end here. Pax.