Whom did the ' sons of God' marry in Genesis 6?
We read in Gen 6:1-2 (KJV):

And it came to pass, when men began to multiply on the face of the earth, and daughters were born unto them,That the sons of God saw the daughters of men that they were fair; and they took them wives of all which they chose.

Continuation of life on earth is programmed in such a manner that male and female offsprings are born to living beings including human beings in sufficiently equal proportion ,although there is a negligible tilt towards female birth among human beings. Now, who the ' sons of God' were ,has been discussed at length in this forum. If there were sons, there were also 'daughters of God'. And if the daughters of men were so fair as to attract the attention of sons of God, the sons of men were also handsome enough to attract the daughters of God. Similarly, the sons of men would fall short of marriageable girls for the reason that many were wedded to sons of God. My question therefore,  is: Whom did the ' sons of men' marry in Genesis 6 ? Are there any pseudo canonical writings or Jewish/ Christian folklore available on the topic ?

One assumes that all were marrying all others.  The fact remains that we are not told so we do not know.

They were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage (saith Jesus). And the flood came and took them all away. The sons of men (Adam) married the daughters of the progeny of Adam. But some (others) left their proper estate and - also - took wives of the progeny of Adam. And there was, thus, a problem so massive (the emphasis being on 'massive') that a global Flood was needed to correct it. This is all very logical if one follows the word of God,

Your question rests on an assumption which is not only not explicit, but can easily be not true.  "Sons of God" as well as "Daughters of Men" can easily be thought of as multi-word lexemes.  In other words, as idioms, fixed phrases, or collocations (ie "fast food").  Words chosen to name the one class do not necessarily imply the existence of the negative of that class. For example, we debunk; but, we don't bunk.   In fact, the juxtaposition of these two terms in this text suggests that the one is somehow opposite of the other.

Your premise is unsubstantiated. "If there were sons, there were also 'daughters of God'" - there's no reason to assume that has to be true.
How you answer this is going to depend on how you understand "sons of God" (haven't looked, but I assume there are questions about this already):

If you understand "sons of God" as being the God-fearing line of Seth and "daughters of men" as the line of Cain, then there are "daughters of God". In that case, the "sons of men" presumably married daughters of men, most likely they also married "daughters of God", but Scripture doesn't say so this can't be more than an educated guess.
If you understand "sons of God" as being angels, then there's no reason to accept your premise that there are "daughters of God". So far as we see in the Bible, angels appear as men or as indescribable creatures with lots of wings and/or wheels. We don't see female angels and we don't really have a reason to assume gender distinction among them. In this case, sons of men definitely married daughters of men, anything beyond that is speculation that can't be supported by Scripture.


Yes. They neither marry nor are given in marriage,. As saith Jesus.

Answer
The ‘sons of men’ married ‘daughters of men’ in Genesis 6. In fact sons of men can marry only daughters of men because of the ‘species barrier’!
Explanation
If Genesis chapter 5 can be viewed as an “inset” in between, the story continues from chapter 4 into chapter 6 as follows:

“And Adam knew his wife again, and she bore a son. And she called his
name, Seth, for God has appointed to me another seed in place of Abel
because Cain killed him. And a son was also born to Seth, and he
called his name, Enos. Then began men to call themselves by the
name of the Lord (This is a marginal reading). And it came about
that men began to multiply on the face of the earth, and daughters
were born to them. The sons of God saw the daughters of men, that they
were good, and they took wives for themselves from all those whom they
chose” (Gen 4:25-26 and Gen 6:1-2 without break).

Today, the elect saints of God are called collectively as the “Church of God”.
In Seth’s and Enos’s time, the elect saints were called collectively as the “Sons of God”. This is what the marginal reading says: “Then began men to call themselves by the name of the Lord”.
But as usual, these men went astray and started to intermarry with women of unbelievers.
But when people read the term ‘sons of God’ they jump to conclusions saying sons of God are angels who married women and procreated hybrid species. This is unwarranted.
The Scripture says:

“Blessed are the peacemakers! For they shall be called sons of
God” (Mat 5:9).


“For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, these are sons of
God” (Rom 8:14).


“For the earnest expectation of the creation eagerly awaits the
revelation of the sons of God” (verse 19).


“for you are all sons of God through faith in Christ Jesus” (Gal
3:26).

Thus the holy believers under the leadership of Seth and Enos were called the Sons of God.
Sons of Men
Sons of men are humanity in general:

“the heavens are Jehovah's, but He has given the earth to the sons
of men” (Psalms 115:16).


“Surely the sons of men are vanity” (Psalms 62:9).

Conclusion
So, surely, the sons of men can marry only the daughters of men because of the species barrier.

The scripture references of "sons of God" you refer to are all in the New Testament, but conveniently left out the references in Job where the same phrase (in the same language) is used to describe angels. And your connection to chapter 4 is a distant one compared to the connection in Gen 6:4 where it says the giants arrived when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men. That's a direct connection, and I don't see how it can be explained away by suggesting godly human men took ungodly women.

@BVernon – I will update my answer with more OT references of sons of God and with other points. I left out Job reference not “conveniently” but “contextually” because angels are asexual as per Jesus’s own witness: “Jesus answered them, "How wrong you are! It is because you don't know the Scriptures or God's power. For when the dead rise to life, they will be like the angels in heaven and will not marry” (Mat 22:29-30).

But these aren't angels in heaven. Was Melchizedek an angel in heaven, or on earth? Angels in heaven can't procreate with humans as you say. If you say Melchizedek was Jesus, then we are at an impass and can agree to disagree. But if not, then who was he a king over?

These aren’t angels in heaven ?! But you said to me, “but conveniently left out the references in Job where the same phrase (in the same language) is used to describe angels” in your first comment. I checked in Job.  It says there that “the sons of God came to present themselves before Jehovah” (Job 1:6; 2:1). Jehovah is in heaven. So these angels are also in heaven. And you have already agreed that “Angels in heaven can't procreate with humans as you say”. So the case should be closed.

Besides Job 38:7 says the sons of God shouted for joy when God laid the foundation of the earth. So, naturally these angels pre-dated the earth and hence could not have been on the earth before. So they (I mean ALL the angels) were definitely angels in heaven.

If you are open... then please consider that everything you just argued is based on the idea that "the sons of God" is the name of a special group. In your opinion, a group of humans, but you're projecting this idea to apply to a special group of angels. I have not said this, and I don't agree with it. It's not established, and to use that in argument is circular reasoning. Once you drop that presupposition, then which of the issues you presented remains? I think not any of them, but maybe you're not convinced so would you review and let me know which points you believe would still stand?

To clarify: 1) Sons of God could refer to angels whether in heaven or on earth, so the Job reference is valid. Angels in Job are in heaven; angels in Genesis are on earth. No problem; case not closed. 2) It sounds like you are making an assumption that angels on earth could not have been around before the earth. I don't know why you would assume that. My assumption is they were around prior., so Job 38:7 would make perfect sense regardless of which angels you're referring to. They are angels like the other angels, but at some point some were put on earth with bodies.

Indeed, the idea that this would be a special group of angels rather than a reference simply interchangeable with "angels", would have to be based on your marginal reading where it says "Then began men to call themselves by the name of the Lord". That verse is clearly talking about men; not angels. So you couldn't possibly use such a presupposition when considering my view, right?

I am open and we are discussing in a positive Christian manner. You have misunderstood me; I said the angels on earth pre-dated the earth, meaning “they were around before the earth” was created but they were angels in heaven and hence “can’t procreate with humans”. I agree with you: “They are angels like the other angels”. BUT..when you say: “but at some point some were put on earth with bodies”, I would say that is an “assumption” because nowhere in the Scripture can we find any such idea. Angels are spirit beings and they have “spiritual bodies” (1 Cor 15:44).

The Scripture calls even the fallen evil angel as “the spirit now working in the sons of disobedience” (Eph 2:2). Even Lord Jesus calls the evil fallen angels as “the unclean spirit” (Mat 12:43) and “7 other spirits more evil” (verse 45). An inspired Paul calls them “the spiritual powers of evil in the heavenlies” (Eph 6:12). So, we see that angels whether holy in heaven or evil on earth are spiritual beings and they have no sexual capability. Your assumption that they were put on earth with bodies has no Scriptural references.

However I gave you several references in my above answer for proving that human saints are called sons of God (without denying that the same term is applied to angels also).

Yes I agree, I am making an assumption... but it's not based on zero scriptural evidence as you suggest: we have the example of Melchizedek. However weak you may feel this evidence is, it's at least as strong as the evidence you provide linking the scripture about men calling on God to the sons of God; which is what your view hinges on, right? I don't mean to say you ought to necessarily agree, but that you ought to at least validate that another equally rational person can reasonably see it this way.

For what's worth, my view is the one taken in both the Book of Enoch and the Book of Adam. I don't mention these to suggest they should be believed as scripture, but to point out that people took this view even well before Christ was born.

In regard to the term Sons of God, we are looking at the the English translations from two different languages. The book of Job uses the same phrase in Hebrew. Though New Testament references translate to "sons of God" in English, I don't believe they would translate to the same phrase used in Hebrew. I will look into this further. While a different topic, I think this is of interest: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/32547/is-the-term-sons-of-god-in-john-112-the-same-categorization-as-sons-of-god

I also notice in the Book of Jasher (not mentioned based on any scriptural authority; but only to show how how the language is used), that sons of God is only used for angels. It covers much of Genesis with varying details, but it leaves out any verse which would correlate to Genesis 6:2. As such, only "sons of men" is used here and never "sons of God". There is, however an additional instance of "sons of God" as it tells about Enoch being translated and it refers to angels. So while not significant, it is at least some additional evidence suggesting the Hebrew phrase always refers to angels.

In conclusion, what I'm saying is that we are both making an assumption. The reason I prefer my assumption is because it doesn't create any discrepancies in scripture... the scriptures would 100% make sense. It also would explain why God destroyed the earth if DNA of men had been corrupted. It not only makes sense, but also brings additional context to make other events make even more sense.

Another tangentially related point: when the giants returned after the flood, notice that the places they inhabited were the places God ordered to be totally destroyed, leaving no one alive.

Sorry for shotguning you with so many comments at once... I just have a moment to do this right now and would like to present all the evidence at once for your consideration. Can you remind me what your problem is with taking the scriptures in Jude in connection with this topic? It references angels who abandoned their proper dwelling, and immediately in the next verse it says "in a similar way" S&G gave themselves over to sexual immorality. It's clearly talking about angels, and it clearly connects them to sexual immorality. Does it not?

I will begin with your last comment upwards. I think there is a misunderstanding on your part in reading Jude 1:7. It does not say the S&G committed sexual immorality “in a similar way” as the angels! Not at all! But it says: “as S&G, and the cities around them in like manner to these (i.e., S&G) committing fornication…”. So, you see, it  is the cities around the S&G who fornicated “in a similar way” as the S&G.

I will give you one more evidence from Scripture for this. Jude talks about 3 categories here: 1) unbelieving Israel from Egypt – crime – “set aside glories and blaspheme” (verse 8); 2) angels – crime – “despise (God’s) rulership” (verse 8); 3) S&G and cities around them “in similar way” – crime – “defile flesh” (sexual immorality).

God did not destroy the earth in a great Flood because “DNA of men had been corrupted”. Not at all! The reason is clearly given in the Scripture: “And Jehovah saw that the evil of MAN was great on the earth, and every imagination of the thoughts (not DNA) of his heart was only evil all the day long” (Gen 6:5). “And Jehovah said, I will wipe off MAN whom I have created from the face of the earth, from man to beast, to the creeping thing and to the birds of the heavens” (verse 7). So, DNA had nothing to do here.

@BVernon, I will read this entire thread after I mention something we sometimes overlook in this instance of angels and sons of God and giants, etc. - Jesus said angels cannot reproduce (Matthew 22:30; Mark 12:25).

@RobCallicotte Technically, he said they aren't given in marriage. He didn't say they lacked the facilities. However, I wouldn't put too much emphasis on that. More telling is the part where it says "angels in heaven". Melchizedek was clearly not a human, yet he lived on earth and ruled over a city... and brought out food and drink. The belief is that he had flesh... just like the angels who "kept not their first estate" mentioned in Jude 1:6.

Hey BVernon! Thanks for answering. I'm not certain I agree about Melchizedek, even though Hebrews shows him as somewhat of a mystery person. I see him rather as a relative unknown to us, but a priest of God during Abraham's time. Hard to prove Melchizedek is not human, isn't it? Would you show me the proof of this in the Bible?

When we consider the concept of the chosen son as the son of God, similar to how God chose Isaac over Ishmael and Jacob over Esau, we notice that Genesis 5 lists only one son from each generation, from Adam to Lamech, who fathered Noah. These sons are also mentioned in the Genealogy of Jesus in Luke 3.
Therefore the term 'sons of God' refers to the chosen sons, while 'daughters of men' refers to any daughters born to men.
The sentence structure in Genesis 5:3-32 is quite consistent. For example, Genesis 5:6-9 states;

6 When Seth had lived 105 years, he became the father of Enosh. 7 After he became the father of Enosh, Seth lived 807 years and had other sons and daughters. 8 Altogether, Seth lived a total of 912 years, and then he died.

Enosh is the chosen son and thus a 'son of God'. Seth also had other sons and daughters, who are referred to as 'sons and daughters of men'.

First, it is not out of the question that human males formed sexual bonds with angels of whatever gender. (Some consider angels to be neuter.) We can deduce this from the story of Sodom, when the men of that town desired sex with the angels that visited Lot.
Regarding female angels, there is a biblical text that provides support (controversially) for the idea:
Zech. 5

9 Then I raised my eyes and saw two women coming forth with wind under
their wings—they had wings like the wings of a stork—and they lifted
the basket into the air.

According to the the Chassidic scholar Adin Even-Israel Steinsaltz:

Perhaps these winged women were angels or some other type of
celestial being; for they have wings shaped like the wings of a stork;
and they lifted the ephah between the earth and the heavens. These
winged women were raising the measure that contained the woman inside
it, so that it was between the heaven and the earth.

Beyond this, a Talmudic tradition holds that an angel called "night" (Layla) is in charge of conception. The word for "night" is feminine but sources are ambiguous concerning this particular angel. According to  Niddah 16b

For R. Hanina b. Papa made the following exposition: The name of the
angel who is in charge of conception is 'Night', and s/he takes up a
drop [of semen] and places it in the presence of the Holy One, blessed be He,
saying, 'Sovereign of the universe, what shall be the fate of this
drop? Shall it produce a strong man or a weak man, a wise man or a
fool, a rich man or a poor man?

As for the question of whom the "sons of men" married; they married the daughters of men. Relatively few women were taken by fallen angels. There is no way of knowing if human males also "married" putative female angels. However, we know from the story of Sodom that human males desired to have sex with angels of whatever gender.

To begin with, Adam is the name of the first man, but also general term that means mankind. This is why the men of the bible can be generically referred to as son's of Adam (ben-adam בֶּן-אָדָם) (Dan 7:13, Ez 2:1, Matt 8:20, Mark 10:45).
In the same way, "The Elohim" is a term for God hā-’ĕ-lō-hîm הָאֱלֹהִ֑ים Deut 4:35) and son's of elohim is a way to refer to other spiritual beings such as the angels (mê-’ĕ-lō-hîm) Psalm 8:5.
However, while women can be called daughters of men (bə·nō·wṯ hā·’ā·ḏām בְּנוֹת הָאָדָם) as in the OP's selected passage Gen 6:1-2 there aren't any examples of female spiritual beings in the biblical texts.
This may seem discordant, but we're not told that angels were made in the image of God. Instead, we're told that man and woman together represent the image of God:

Genesis 1:27 (NRSV): So God created humankind in his image, in the
image of God he created them; male and female he created them.
Genesis 2:21 So the LORD God caused a deep sleep to fall upon the man,
and he slept; then he took one of his ribs and closed up its place
with flesh. 22 And the rib that the LORD God had taken from the man he
made into a woman and brought her to the man.
Genesis 2:24 Therefore a man leaves his father and his mother and clings to his wife, and they become one flesh.

So, to answer the OP's question there are no daughters of God revealed in the text. However, the union of the son's of God and daughters of men did result in the creation of the Nephalim (giants) who play a prominent role throughout the period from the Fall of Creation to the books of the Kings.
These spawn of spirtual beings and mankind are referred to as the Nephalim, Anaq, Rephaim, Emim, Zamzummim, and Gibborim. The most famous of which is Goliath of Gath. See links to relavent verses.
